# Kendo UI Grid: Method "removeRow" deletes all events of the grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo UI Grid and added mouse events to the grid by jQuery (e.g. click). This is working without any problem. But by deleting a row in the grid, all events of the grid are also deleted. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code to delete a row:

```
var rowToDelete = $(this).closest("tr");
var grid = $("#gridId").data("kendoGrid");
grid.removeRow(rowToDelete);
```

I added a button to each row of the grid, added a click event to these buttons which deletes the corresponding row. After the row is deleted, the click events of all other buttons are removed. The same with the mouse-over events of a grid column.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Of course I can add all events again after deleting the row, but this solution doesn't seem to be very elegant.

Comment: Can you please provide information about which event you have added in this grid/row?

Comment: It's just a simple jQuery-Event, e.g.: '$('#gridId .k-grid-content table tr').click(function () { alert('row clicked!') });'

Comment: Ok, i will try to resolved this issue and inform you. In this time can you please check that issue is: "Sometimes alert break the functionality of kendo ui so can you please change the code (on row click change the color of text) of click event and check it again".

Comment: alert() was just an example... it doesn't matter which event I'm binding. In fact, I'm doing just a simple '$("#someDivId").addClass("someClass")'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**VIEW**

```
<script>
function gridDataBound(e) {
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.tbody.find(">tr").click(function () {
        $("#divTest").html('Row Index Clicked :' + $(this).index());
    });
}

function DeleteRow(obj) {
    var rowToDelete = $(obj).parent().parent()
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.removeRow(rowToDelete);
}
</script>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcApplication1.Models.TestModels>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.ID);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
    columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='button' class='k-button' value='Delete' onclick='DeleteRow(this);' />");

})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Grid_Read", "Home"))
)
.Events(e => e.DataBound("gridDataBound"))
)
<div id="divTest"></div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Grid_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        List<TestModels> models = new List<TestModels>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            TestModels t1 = new TestModels();
            t1.ID = i;
            t1.Name = "Name" + i;
            models.Add(t1);
        }

        return Json(models.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public class TestModels
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: This is working! But it is quite the same solution as to bind the events again after pressing the button, because the dataBound-Event is fired every time the grid is modified. So the events are getting deleted and afterwards added again.

Comment: Because once we delete any row from the grid it will rebind the data. So it will regenerate the row that's why your assigned event is removed.

Answer (score 2):

You are not posting all the code so I have to guess...

What is happening is that you set an event handler associated to the elements just after the initialization and therefore for some particular HTML elements **but** there are circumstances under which Kendo UI grid gets regenerated (basically the system removes the table and generates a new one).

If you want to set an event handler not for the current table content but for any future one, you might use jQuery `on` event but using three arguments where the second is the selector (in previous version of jQuery this was achieved with `live` function but now is deprecated, so if your jQuery version supports it better use `on`).

What you have to do is:

```
$("#grid").on("click", ".my-selector", function(e) {
    var rowToDelete = $(this).closest("tr");
    var grid = $("#gridId").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.removeRow(rowToDelete);
});
```

Where `my-selector` is a CSS `class` attribute that you probably already set for identifying the `remove` button.

Comment: Thanks, very good solution! This is working for what I have asked in my question. But if you have to do other things (than binding events), this will not work, I guess? For example, I'm having a dropdown list in the grid which I have to generate with some Kendo-JS-Code. I have to recreate this dropdown list after the grid was modified.

Comment: Where is that Drop Down List? In a row, in a cell...?

Comment: Yes, in a cell. The dropdown list is just standard html, then i have to create the kendo dropdown list out of it...

Comment: If it is a cell then you are probably creating the dropdown list using a template, since the cell is _hanging_ from $("#grid"), it should work. What this `on` does is add a function that everytime a DOM node is inserted in the subtree and matches the selector, it adds the event handler.

Comment: OK, thank you very much! I tried to use a template, but it didn't fit my needs. Because I need a JS-function to get some values via an ASP.NET MVC Action from the database.

Comment: No problem -at least using JS- if you define the dropdown list using a DataSource, it should be able of getting the data from any KendoUI valid DataSource...